# angularfire2@5 's AngularFireDatabase.object('path-to-item').valueChanges() returns Observable<{}> instead of Observable<any>?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I just got started with angularfire2 version 5, trying to assign interfaces to objects returned from AngularFireDatabase.object method but am getting error at type checking: Type 'Observable<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Observable'

The project is generated with Angular 7.

```
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireObject } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ShoppingCart } from './models/shopping-cart';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ShoppingCartService {

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { 

  }

  async getCart(): Promise<Observable<ShoppingCart>> {
    let cartId = await this.getOrCreateCartId();
    return this.db.object('/shopping-carts/' + cartId).valueChanges();
  }
}
```

The error disappears if I don't annotate the getCart method, and in such case, getCart method is shown to return a promise Observable of {}.
So why doesn't AngularFireDatabase.object('...').valueChanges() return promise Observable of type **any** like it's supposed to? And how can I assign a type interface to the objects returned from AngularFireDatabase.object('...').valueChanges()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install the official Firebase library for angular

**npm install firebase @angular/fire --save**

refactor your `getOrCreateCartId` method to return observable instead of promise

and then use this

`getCart(): Observable<ShoppingCart> {
    return this.getOrCreateCartId()
      .pipe(
        switchMap((cartId: string) => {
          const cart = this.db.doc<ShoppingCart>('shopping-carts/' + cartId);
          return cart.valueChanges();
        })
      )
}`

otherwise if you still wanna promise to return

```
async getCart(): Observable<ShoppingCart> {
       const cardId = await this.getOrCreateCartId();
       const cart = this.db.doc<ShoppingCart>('shopping-carts/' + cartId);
       return cart.valueChanges().toPromise();
}
```

but aware that since you **`toPromise`** have been used you'll

**Notice** that you can convert any type of data to observable using **`from()`**

Comment: Thanks! Thanks to your answer, I found out that annotating <ShoppingCart> to this.db.doc|object method solves the issue!